# How to set the encoding of an embedded text iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am here asking about document embedding in HTML.

In a project I am working on, I am embedding my update logs as text files directly into my page, with a selection menu to view all the different updates.

The problem I am having, is not really much of a problem, being that they are plain text files, but the Firefox (have not tested elsewhere yet) console spits out a "No character encoding in the iframe document" warning.

I have searched far and wide for a solution to this problem, only to find that every solution is specifically main-level document based, like "put a  tag in the html header", which I already have done from the start. I just use this:

```
<embed id="update_display" src="some_latest_update_file.txt" />
```

The embed seems to create an iframe, with the text file as the source. This works fine for me, where I am just displaying the updates. But what I am trying to control is the warning, I don't want to see the warning for something stupid like that. I know I can display my updates differently, but I would like to  keep the current method if possible.

Is there a way to set the encoding of the iframe, without actually knowing the id or anything about what the embed will create?

It creates an entirely different document within my document, with it's own html, head, body and such tags. I would greatly appreciate any answer for this, as I want to keep my console clean and warning/error free.

Comment: Is the text file being loaded over HTTP?

Comment: no, just from a list of text files from a folder in the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never actually ended up sticking with this, I just used `<object src='somefile'></object>` instead and included the encoding in the source file.